# Sprite refuses to turn invisible when setting sprite.visible = false

Tags: javascript, visible, code.org

All I want is for startButton to disappear after clicking on it and for it to be tinted when the mouse hovers over it. For some reason, startButton refuses to disappear when I click it. The tinting thing is working fine though. By the way, I am working in code.org's gamelab. createSprite is one of their functions.

```js
function draw() {
  var startButton = createSprite(200, 200, 150, 75);
  startButton.setAnimation("startButton");
  if(mouseIsOver(startButton)){
    startButton.tint = "lightGray";
  }
  if(mouseWentUp()){
    startButton.visible = false;
    drawSprites();
    console.log("start");
  }
  drawSprites();
}
draw();
```

Comment: unless you explain where `createSprite` comes from, e.g. what library you're even using, we have no way to answer your question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans From [code.org](https://studio.code.org/s/csd3-2020/stage/7/puzzle/2)

Comment: Remember that if there's a request for more details, those details [should go in your post](/help/how-to-ask), so please remember to update your post with that information. The comments thread should not be necessary to answer your question =)

Comment: `createSprit()` is not a standard JavaScript function. Please [edit] your question with more details to help us understand what you are trying to do. See [ask] and [mcve] for tips to improve your question so we can answer it.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry about that. This is only my second question. Anyway, I am using code.org's gamelab feature and createSprite is one of their functions.